# postfix specify limited relay domain while allowing sasl-auth relay

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp

I'm trying to set up postfix to allow relaying under a limited set of conditions:

- The destination domain is one of a pre-defined list
  *-or-*
- The client successfully logs in

Here's the relevant bits o' config:

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
relay_domains=example.com
smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_auth_destination,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

The problem is that it requires that BOTH restrictions be satisfied, rather than either-or. Which is to say, it only allows relaying if the client is authenticated AND the recipient domain is @example.com.

Instead, I need it to allow relaying if either one of the requirements is satisfied. How do I do this without resorting to running SMTP on two separate ports with different rules?

*Note:

The context is an outbound-use-only (bound to 127.0.0.1) MTA on a shared web server which all site owners are allowed to relay mail to one of the "owned" domains (not server-local, though), and for which a limited set of "trusted" site owners are allowed to relay mail without restriction provided they have a valid SMTP login.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And of course I figure it out 6 minutes after posting the question.

You can put `permit_sasl_authenticated` in your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` setting and remove the `smtpd_client_restrictions` altogether.

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
relay_domains=example.com
smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_auth_destination,
     permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
```

The fact that this option is not documented in http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions has proved to be a source of not an insignificant amount of frustration in this case.

Comment: Yep. Great documentation and super useful errors in the logs make working with Postfix uber fun.